# Why is the brk() system call necessary?

Tags: linux

AFAIK, after the brk() syscall, the extra virtual memory has not yet been allocated (i.e the page table has not grown to accommodate the new virtual addresses). My impression is that these page tables are added as

So... why do you need the brk() syscall to exist at all? Why can't the kernel just create page tables as necessary, as memory accesses come in?

Comment: Added as what? I think you left out part of your sentence.

Comment: I think you're wrong about what `brk()` does. It does add them to the page table, but marks them as unmapped. When you take a page fault in that page, it will allocate an empty page of memory and map to it.

Comment: If the kernel added pages whenever you accessed an unmapped page, you wouldn't get segmentation violations when you use an uninitialized pointer. Also, how would it know what the proper access control should be for the new page?

Comment: @Barmar oh, shoot. I think the confusion comes from what information actually exists in the page table, and exactly how it works. Thanks.

Comment: This isn't really a programming question, but a question about OS design. I suggest you read a textbook on the design of Unix.

Answer (score 1):

That would not help you catch writes to unallocated memory.